# Find item in list with closing parenthesis

Tags: c#

I have a list of string where item X has an opening paranthesis. How can I find the item with the closing one?

My list:

```
list[0] = "first line of string";
list[1] = "opening parenthesis here (";
list[2] = "third line of string";
list[3] = "making something here(blabla";
list[4] = "blabla)";
list[5] = "closing parenthesis here)";
list[6] = "last line of string";
```

I wan't the to get all items from opening parenthesis to close parenthesis. How can I do this in a smart and easy way?

Comment: Keep count of the opening pars. Once the count is 0 again, you have the matching paren.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to the problem :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
    List<int> Opened = new List<int>();
    List<int> Closed = new List<int>();

    list.Add("first line of string");
    list.Add("opening parenthesis here (");
    list.Add("third line of string");
    list.Add("making something here(blabla");
    list.Add("blabla)");
    list.Add("closing parenthesis here)");
    list.Add("last line of string");


    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].Contains("("))
            Opened.Add(i);
        else if (list[i].Contains(")"))
            Closed.Add(i);
    }
    string Result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Opened.Count; i++)
    {
        Result += "Opened at " + Opened[i].ToString() + " and closed at " + (Closed[Closed.Count - i - 1]) + "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Nice proposition. Just require a few controls to avoid Index out of array exception and so.

Comment: @Richard 100% i took the fact that all the parenthesis are going to be closed, that's all :p

Comment: And I understand that ! OP is free to improve your code, you did most of the work for him. I have upvoted your answer.